# Symfony2 Secure by IP not working

Tags: security, symfony, yaml

In my Symfony 2.3.1 Security YML, I have this line.

security.yml

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/mysecurearea, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 0.0.0.0 }
```

Based on this:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html

I was under the impression that this route and routes like it, e.g. /mysecurearea/something should only be accessible to a request from IP 0.0.0.0

Problem is, I can still access it.

Any ideas?

Comment: are you logged when trying to access mysecurearea ?

Comment: No. I worked out what the issue is, but I will wait a couple of days and see if anyone else comes up with the answer. Then I can give them points by marking their answer as correct.

Comment: Did you clear your cache? What is in your firewalls section?

Comment: Cache is fine. The firewall just has login info for /^, but that doesn't effect access to anything. e.g. IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY has access to /^

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, all I wanted to do, was stop people from access an area, unless they had a valid IP. What I hadn't entirely appreciated, was that access_control can only give roles, rather than deny access. (Makes sense in hindsight.)

```
    - { path: ^/mysecurearea, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 0.0.0.0 }
    - { path: ^/mysecurearea, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

So to achieve what I was looking for, I needed to add the additional line above.
ROLE_NO_ACCESS doesn't actually exist. You just need to add some text there which is descriptive and note a valid role. Since it isn't a valid role, the requester can no longer access the area.
It is a bit of a hack, but for my purposes, it does the job perfectly.

Comment: If I use this solution I always get "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" having a firewall rule in place (`login_path: /login  use_forward: false`). What can I do?

Comment: It suggests that where they are being bumped to, is not accessible to that user either. e.g. When Symfony can't match for the area, it redirects/forwards the user to the login page. Thus if it can't match for the login page either, then it will get into an infinite loop. Is an anonymous user able to access the login page?

Comment: No the complete login should only be possible for certain ip addresses. How can I fix this? That login and everything restricted shows a "not found" if it is called from a non allowed ip address and second that if it is the right ip the person accessing restricted areas is redirected to the login, just as normally.

Comment: made a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33653483/symfony-2-securing-login-with-ip) from my comment

Answer (score 3):

My **security.yml** had some default entries that were somehow causing it to ignore the IP rules. I don't have any login functionality so my use case is quite simple.

Here is my entire security.yml that works for me in Symfony 2.3.6:

```
security:
    firewalls:
        anonymous:
            anonymous: ~

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/foo, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ips: [127.0.0.1, ::1] }
        - { path: ^/foo, roles: ROLE_NO_ACCESS }
```

Just change the `^/foo` path and the list of IPs.